# Finding PDF from CDF

Tags: probability, self-study, density-function, cumulative-distribution-function, derivative

I just got really unsure, can someone confirm/rectify? I have the CDF defined as $F(x)= \begin{cases}0, &\text{if}~x < 0,\\ 4x^2 &\text{if}~  0 \leq x < \frac{1}{4} \\ 1-\frac{4}{3}(1-x)^2 & \text{if}~ \frac{1}{4} \leq x < 1, \\
1, &\text{if}~ x \geq 1. \end{cases}   $

I want to find the PDF, is it simply $f(x)=8x \mathbb{1}_{0\leq x< \frac{1}{4}} + \frac{8}{3}(1-x) \mathbb{1}_{\frac{1}{4} \leq x < 1}$ ?

Thanks

Comment: Sorry there is a typo in pdf, I meant (1-x) (not (1-x)^2)

Comment: and 8x  not 8x^2 ?  Also,  it looks like there are some spurious 1's in your formula.   You should be able to edit your question to fix these errors.

Comment: Yes sorry I meant 8x... The 1's are indicator functions

Comment: You might want to be careful with the limits. CDFs are right continuous so I think the limit should be <1/4 instead of ≤ 1/4.

Comment: @MossMurderer $4(1/4)^2=1/4=1-4/3(3/4)^2$ so it doesn't matter in this case

Comment: Your pdf is correct. You can always verify by integration if you're unsure.

Comment: Your CDF is incompletely defined. The CDF $F(x)$ is the probability that the random variable $X$ is no larger than $x$. Thus, the CDF is defined for _all_ $x$, is a nondecreasing function of $x$, and it must approach value $1$ (or have value $1$) as $x$ tends to $\infty$. In this instance, the CDF _has_ value $1$ at $x=1$ and it continues to have this value for all $x>1$ too. And yes, the pdf is the derivative of the CDF and it is (almost) what you find it to be; you don't need to worry about discontinuities in $F(x)$.

Comment: Depending on taste, one could also restrict the range of $x$ to something different than $\mathbb{R}$. For instance an interval $\lbrace x \in \mathbb{R}  \;\vert\; 0 \leq x \leq 1 \rbrace$.

Comment: @MartijnWeterings "Taste" sometimes is not rigorous, if not incorrect. Every distribution function of a random variable must be defined at every point in $\mathbb{R}^1$ --- it's not about the "range of $x$", but the domain of $F$.

Comment: Oh, yes, of course. First, I interpret the "PDF" in your comment as "CDF", and the CDF of a discrete random variable is a step-function defined on $\mathbb{R}$, where the jumps occur at mass points. Second, I interpret your "$\mathbb{R}^2$" as $\mathbb{R}$. The domain of a distribution function $F$ must be $\mathbb{R}$, instead of any proper subsets of $\mathbb{R}$. This is because in order a function $F$ to be a distribution function, by definition, we require $\lim_{x \to -\infty}F(x) = 0$ and $\lim_{x \to +\infty} F(x) = 1$.

Comment: If, as you proposed, we only defined $F$ on $[0, 1]$, then how would you make sense to talk about the two limits above? Yes, it is "just a definition thing", but any formal definition should be clear, flawless and unambiguous, right?

Comment: @MartijnWeterings Based on your question about the discrete random variables, I suppose you have confused the concepts of ***probability mass function*** and  ***probability distribution function***. The former, indeed, doesn't need its domain to be $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: @MartijnWeterings What kind of example do you want? The $F$ in this post that was modified by Dilip Sarwate provided a good example on how to display a cdf correctly and unambiguously. Admittedly, people tend to "truncate" the $0$ and $1$ parts ruthlessly. I think to avoid such incorrect practice when presenting a distribution function is the point Dilip and me wanted to make here.

Comment: I am looking forward to your question :)